# Transferring data from a textbox to unboundstring on crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to display a textbox to my crystal report as a modification of what I have started. My datatable is already working and I would like to transfer a text from a textbox directly to crystal report unboundstring. I am having issues. Here's my code sample. Can you please help me. I am having specific issue with this line

```
((TextObject)objRpt.Section2.ReportObjects["@UnboundString1"]).Text = TextBox1.text;
```

Thanks.

This is the Error:
 Unable to cast object of type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FieldObject' to type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject'.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;
            connectionString = "data source=SERVER; initial catalog= DBO ;user id=sa; password= password";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "select Leave_Type as DataColumn1,Reason as DataColumn2, Date_From as DataColumn4, Date_To as DataColumn5 from Leave_Application where Badge_Number = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        cnn.Close();

        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();        

        dscmd.Fill(ds, "DataTable1");

        EmployeeLeave objRpt = new EmployeeLeave();
        ((TextObject)objRpt.Section2.ReportObjects["@UnboundString1"]).Text = TextBox1.text;

        objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();




    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The error states it clearly, you are trying to convert a FieldObject to a TextObject which is impossible.

- A **FieldObject** is created when you add onto the report an object like a Database Field, a Formula Field, a Parameter Field etc.
- A **TextObject** is created if you right click inside a section area and select Insert -> Text Object.

My first observation is that you are using a Formula Field, since the **@UnboundString1** begins with the at "@" symbol. Secondly you must not use the name that appears inside the report to refer to a field, but the name of the object that appears in the Properties window.

To create an unbound field, either you can create a TextObject and use the approach that you have already used or you can create a Parameter and set its value with the SetParameterValue method.

Answer (score 1):

try this with VB

```
'pass texbox2 to unbounddate1
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("unbounddate1").Text = "'" &
Me.TextBox2.Text & "'" 'pass texbox3 to unbounddate2
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("unbounddate2").Text = "'" &
Me.TextBox3.Text & "'"
```